# remove script tags from loaded in content using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a learning CMS that we are reskinning. We have 1000s of units that contain HTML including javascript lib loads, and I am having conflicts with the versions of the libraries in the units and those loaded in the skin..esp jQuery, but there are other I want to remove.

I have tried using remove() at the bottom of the page, but by the time it loads, the other library has already loaded in. If I put it at the top of the page, it won't work as the script does not appear yet.

No sure how to work this one out..

Thanks

Comment: Can you not remove them loading from the HTML itself?

Comment: I have literally 1000s of these instances. It is a legacy system and hard coding them into the HTML was needed in the past. The HTML comes out of a database, but the db admins don't want to do a search and remove over the entire system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not your concern, you can write yourself a light framework.
Every page will be sort of loaded twice.

e.g., whenever your page is requested,
your backend will always return the 'one' page, within this page:

1. load jquery
2. send ajax request to e.g., http://someurl.com/pages/index?some_flag=second_load
3. get the return as plain text
4. strip  and remove  tags
5. $('html').html( /* the stripped page content */ )

and for http://someurl.com/pages/index?some_flag=second_load

once your backend detects that some_flag == 'second_load',
return the true content of the page.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/WA7tv/5/

Personally I don't regard this as a good way, just for your question specifically ... highly recommend a code refactorization

Comment: Thanks..that should work..I'm still working on the admins to change their mind though ;)